# Which type of application?

Tags: web-application, publishing

I would like to create an application which will converts images from SharePoint's list to other format, change properties, save new images etc. I would like to put this code on some server (Azure web app) because I don't want to use a JavaScript client code to this operation (I want to work on bigger data so I want to involve some C# code). In the future, I would like to make this application available for SharePoint Online and SharePoint on premise and put this app to store. Which type of application should I use? Now, my idea of application contains this elements:

- SharePoint provided-hosted app (low-trust)- I can use back-end code
- MVC pattern -  I can create controllers to perform specific operations and I have back-end logic to perform operations on files.
- C# CSOM (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) library - easy access to list items and Sharepoint's elements
- Azure Web Application - hosting web part with c# logic code on azure (integration with SharePoint).

Is it a good configuration for SharePoint Online or SharePoint on premise? Is it possible to put this type of application on Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provider hosted app runs from a 3rd party server (Ex Azure VM). In this VM you need to setup IIS etc and configure your web app. I guess this setup will work fine for your application.